# How do i send ( export ) barplots to a directory or folder instead of displying them on screen

Tags: r

hi all 
I wish to save multiple barplots to a directory or folder 
That is, On each iteration my program creates a barplot (hundreds in total) and i wish to direct them to a folder instead of displaying them to the screen.
since i am new to R if possible to explain step by step.
thanks 
yigeal

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you mean saving your graphics as PNG or PDF. Here is a snippet of R code that shows how to redirect plotting action to such graphics devices:

```
WD <- "~/out"  # set your output directory here
k <- 10        # 10 loops for simulated data

for (i in 1:k) {
  png(sprintf(paste(WD, "Rplot%03d.png", sep="/"), i))
  barplot(table(sample(LETTERS[1:6], 100, rep=TRUE)))
  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: @Yigael Should you want to specify a different output directory, just change `WD` to point to the right folder. You can also change the prefix `Rplot` by anything you find more appropriate (btw, if you have 1000 plots, you should better use `%04d` instead of `%03d` so that plot get consecutive numbers, already sorted in your directory). For PDF output, replace `png` with `pdf`.

Comment: Would you be so kinds as to look at my script? can i send it to you for some reason it is not doing what i wish it to do. if i can. how do i go about sending it? is is to long for a comment

Comment: @Yigael It's better to update your question, including your code, IMO. This way, everybody can see it, benefit from the answer provided therein, or come with a better answer. Another solution, put it on a [pastie](http://pastie.org/) or [gist](https://gist.github.com/), and give us the link.

Answer (score 1):

see help for png and pdf functions:

```
?png
?pdf

pdf('fileName', width= 8.5, height= 11)
## some plotting commands...
dev.off()
```

Comment: file name is only one file and i wish to save in a folder multiple plots each in different name. say the name is the same as the title of in the barplot command.

Comment: say i wish to save 1000 barplots each in a different name in a folder named my myPlots